# When trying to run an app on an external device, the console says everything is going smoothly but nothing happens. Why?

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

So right now I'm trying to run [the default Hello World! app](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html) from developers.android.com. I have installed the usb drivers for my SGSII, and it shows up as a device I can use to run the app on. When I select it, this is what appears in the console. This, and nothing more:

```
[2013-02-03 23:41:14 - FirstApp] Android Launch!
[2013-02-03 23:41:14 - FirstApp] adb is running normally.
[2013-02-03 23:41:14 - FirstApp] Performing com.sweatyreptile.chee.firstapp.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-02-03 23:41:14 - FirstApp] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2013-02-03 23:41:16 - FirstApp] Uploading FirstApp.apk onto device '3afd08de'
[2013-02-03 23:41:16 - FirstApp] Installing FirstApp.apk...
[2013-02-03 23:41:45 - FirstApp] Success!
[2013-02-03 23:41:45 - FirstApp] Starting activity com.sweatyreptile.chee.firstapp.MainActivity on device 3afd08de
```

Nothing appears to happen on the device.

EDIT: Like I said, I'm just trying to run the default app that is generated by creating a new android application project.

EDIT 2: So I was able to get the app working on a tablet on my first try, but the phone still doesn't work. Could it have to do with the phone being rooted with a custom rom, while the tablet is stock?

## Code:

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.sweatyreptile.chee.firstapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sweatyreptile.chee.firstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.sweatyreptile.chee.firstapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is your minimum api level?

Comment: Level 8, which is Android 2.2, and my phone is running 4.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I (sort of) found where the issue was. I was using a custom ROM for my Samsung Galaxy S2, called Infamous. It must have had issues that prevented something from working.

After installing a stock (but still rooted and deodexed) ROM, adb was able to install and launch my app with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

To run your application in your emulator change the settings as below and select your emulator as per the target or minimum api level:

Right click on your application and goto `Run As>Run Configurations...`

In `Run configuration` select `Target` tab and in that tab check the radio button `Always prompt to pick device` and then `Apply & Ok`.

After doing above your eclips will always asks you to select your already run emulators if they are as configured as your applications api.

Comment: I have an emulator up that runs the app just fine. The issue is getting the app to work on my Samsung Galaxy S2

Comment: That means that error occurs when you try to run  your application in Samsung Galaxy S2 ?

Comment: No error ever explicily appeared, the app just didn't open, and even though it said it installed, it didn't show up on the list of applications.

Comment: I think there should not be any issue if you are selecting the proper compatible device for your application. I have also tested your code in Samsung Galaxy S2 also but it doesn't show me any error up till now..